# How to set a gif/video as a terminal background?

Tags: command-line, customization, desktop-background, konsole, gif

As stated in the title, I want to have a moving terminal background. I'm currently using Konsole which does accept gif files as a background, however only the first frame is displayed. Can any of you help me make it work?
(I want a background with subtle static noise and glow line, much like in cool-retro-term.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, `terminology` can do this. Install it with:

```
sudo apt install terminology
```

Then, if you really, really want to do this, and on your head be it, but yes, you can set an animated background if that's really something you want to inflict upon yourself. right click on the terminal, then choose settings and then "Wallpaper". Now, enter the path of the animated gif you want to use. I used [this one](http://www.gifbin.com/bin/012013/1358274004_trust_fall_fail.gif) (I saved it in `~/.config/terminology/backgrounds`).

Comment: Your link returns "Page not found".

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix thanks, fixed. It's irrelevant though, just a random gif I found. I wanted to post a screencast showing the animated background but it's too heavy.